# Grails sign up with Modal Window

Tags: grails, modal-dialog, sign

I am using grails 2.1.1 and trying to sign up a new user with modal window. My signup modal window's .gsp code is as follows...

```
....
    <!--Start of Registration Modal Page-->
<div id="register" class="modal hide fade" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
            <i class="icon-remove"></i>
        </button>
            <h3 id="modalLabel">
                Register
            </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <g:form method="POST">
        <div class="controls controls-row">
            <div class="span1"></div>
            <input type="text" class="span2" placeholder="Full Name" value="${user?.profile?.fullName}">
            <div class="span1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="controls controls-row">
            <div class="span1"></div>
            <input type="text" class="span3" placeholder="Email" value="${user?.profile?.email}">
            <div class="span1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="controls controls-row">
            <div class="span1"></div>
            <input type="text" class="span3" placeholder="Username" value="${user?.username}">
            <div class="span1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="controls controls-row">
            <div class="span1"></div>
            <input type="password" class="span3" placeholder="Password" value="${user?.password}">
            <div class="span1"></div>
         </div>
            <div class="controls controls-row">
                <div class="span1"></div>
                <input type="text" class="span3" placeholder="Bio" value="${user?.profile?.bio}">
                <div class="span1"></div>
            </div>
        <div class="controls controls-row">
            <div class="span1"></div>
            <button type="submit" class="span3 btn btn-warning">Create Account</button>
            <div class="span1"></div>
        </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel
        </button>

        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Register
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</g:form><!--End of Form-->
<!--End of Registration Modal Page-->
```

My corresponding controller is "user" and I have a customized "register" action there as well. All I want is that when I click Create Account button, the user is registered behind in the database. Is there any way to make it up through modal window form directly?

Comment: did you tried using formRemote on the modal window?

Comment: Yes, I did. But there is a problem that I do not know what to do with my Create Account button type. Using formRemote tag, when I click Create Account button, nothing happens.

Comment: change your form tag to:  <g:form action="register" controller="user">
and then check on your register action on the controller.